# Is there any way to insert csv file data using cassandra stress?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-stress-tool

I have explored bit on cassandra stress tool using yaml file and it is working fine. I just wanted to know is there anyway by which we can specify the location of any external csv file in yaml profile to insert data into Cassandra table using cassandra stress?

So instead of random data i wanted to see the cassandra stres test result on specific dataload on this data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard `cassandra-stress` doesn't have such functionality, but you can use the [NoSQLBench tool](http://docs.nosqlbench.io/) that was recently open sourced by DataStax. It also uses YAML to describe workloads, but it's much more flexible, and has a [number of functions for sampling data from CSV files](http://docs.nosqlbench.io/#/docs/bindings%2Ffuncref_general).

P.S. there is also a separate [Slack workspace for this project](http://nosqlbench.slack.com/) (to get invite, fill [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdUOJ8iAPqyxsLfh1nBBsKShI53RAeuzYW4bKExmRMWjj4ufQ/viewform))